# How to stop appending the id of assembly build to context root in maven-assembly-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a maven build that uses the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create a war for deployment.  Using the maven-assembly-plugin adds the [assembly ID](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) to the context root of my war though, which I don't want.

I've tried:

```
<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
```

in the `<configuration>` block of the plugin, but that only excludes the id from being appended to the final name (the output file), it doesn't affect the context root.

Is there a way to stop the maven-assembly-plugin from appending the ID to the war's context root parameters?

**Edit:**

The assembly file is used to build a portlet version of the webapp.  In the assembly XML file, there is this line:

```
<id>portlet</id>
```

The context root of the non-portlet webapp is `portal`, so the context root of the portlet built from the assembly ends up being `portal-portlet`.

I need the context root of the two builds to be the same because I am building a flex swf that relies on that context root in the MessageBroker.  I know I could do this by compiling two separate swfs, but that would lead to pom changes I don't want to make for various reasons.

Comment: Can you show the context root you get in your case? Personally I've never used assembly plugin for packaging a war file. Why not use war plugin?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov, I've updated the post.  I have to use the assembly plugin for the portlet build.